# Longevity of SharePoint Full Trust Solutions

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, office-365, support

What is the future for SharePoint Full Trust solutions?  Will support be sunset beyond the next major release of SharePoint?

If full trust solutions are to end at some point in the future then what is the alternative to storing confidential data in the cloud?  Many of our clients are either unable (due to regulation) or un-willing to allow their data to be stored off-premises.

A hybrid solution (On-Premises + SharePoint Online) is acceptable today; but for how long will on-premises technology exist to support this hybrid solution?

Answer (score 1):

The next major release of SharePoint will continue to support FTC, Microsoft will not commit to a release after SharePoint 2015 as of right now (just as Microsoft has never committed to releases after the next announced major version in the past). Nothing says you have to use "the cloud" for any SharePoint solution, even high-trust SharePoint Apps allow you to store data within your own data centers.

Comment: Do you have references for the statements? To me the answers to this question is only known (or is it) by Microsoft at this point? I know you MVP's get more info than most people but I have not seen any official information about this

Answer (score 1):

@TrevorSeward is correct.  I don't have specific ref's to add but I have heard this from various MS event snippets, as well from a MS Field Engineer (for whatever that's worth).

Your other question however doesn't seem to have much to do with Full Trust solutions at all.  If clients are unwilling to store data in the cloud - then you don't have a cloud option, at least not a shared one.  You can look at some type of co-location where your equipment is hosted by a data center and you maintain all links and control. But the argument here is shifting very quickly in favor of the cloud with only a few exceptions.

The biggest threats are the same on-premise and in the cloud.

1. The parts that you control and how you have configured access
2. Users

As far as law enforcement and government access - that is another topic all together, but you can make a good case for cloud hosting against this as well.